# transforming the visible portion of the content in the viewport

Tags: html, css

How can I use CSS to transform only the visible part of a div in the viewport. Here is an  [example](http://tympanus.net/Development/SidebarTransitions/)  of what I mean. Particularly, when you click on "SCALE DOWN PUSHER", the content get scaled down. What's interesting is that only the portion that's in the view port get scaled and the rest of the div is ignored. Much like a screenshot that was taken from the viewport and then shrinked. How do you do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact issue you're running into? What have you tried so far to fix it? Do you have any code to share? Have you tried right-clicking and inspecting the page's content to see what is happening?

Comment: @badAdviceGuy I have my content in a wrapper that's about twice the height of my viewport, I use Javascript to trigger the transition to scale down the wrapper. The problem is, the whole wrapper get scaled, and I want the transform origin to be at the center of the viewport. You will notice in the example I posted is that only the visible part get scaled as if the rest of the wrapper is cut out. I tried to set the height of the wrapper to 100% but that didn't do it. I also inspected the page but I couldn't see a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this on wrapper?

```
position: relative;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

I can't comment so am answering like this

Comment: +1 I believe this is the key. On the example page you can find `.st-content { overflow-y: scroll; }` which the same element that gets scaled. Not sure why you added `position: relative;` though?

Comment: overflow-y: scroll; did it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: just to be sure :) i see in that code that `.st-content` is relative too.